# What type of miniature clover is growing with yellow flowers in my short Australian lawn?

Tags: lawn, identification, grass

I have a weed in my lawn which is prolific where the grass is of low height.  It is a very small clover with yellow flowers.

I live in the Sydney, Australia region.

Here's a photo with a ruler to scale:

[image]

1 inch = 2.54 centimeters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe what you have there is [Yellow Woodsorrel *(Oxalis stricta)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalis_stricta).

If it isn't, I'm 90 to 95% certain it's in the [Oxalis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalis) genus, which Yellow Woodsorrel belongs to...

- [Yellow Wood Sorrel](http://www.herbiguide.com.au/Descriptions/hg_Yellow_Wood_Sorrel.htm) via HerbiGuide (Australia)
- [Yellow woodsorrel](http://www.turf.uiuc.edu/weed_web/descriptions/oxalis.htm) via Midwest Sod Council
- [Yellow Woodsorrel](http://www.ppws.vt.edu/scott/weed_id/oxast.htm) via Virginia Tech Weed Identification Guide

Kudos to [Lisa](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/397/lisa) for the local [Down Under](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_Under) information:

- Where I come from ([SA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Australia)) it's called ["Soursob"](http://www.dpi.vic.gov.au/dpi/vro/vrosite.nsf/pages/weeds_herbs_perennial_soursob) and as far as I know its binomial name is [*Oxalis pes-caprae*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalis_pes-caprae). It is an extremely well known weed throughout the agricultural regions of Australia and some studies identify it as a health risk for grazing livestock. You can use it as a herb apparently, though most people spend countless hours of their lives trying to kill it!
- From [891's Talkback Gardening with Jon Lamb and Ashley Walsh](http://www.abc.net.au/local/stories/2010/02/15/2819886.htm) podcast, listen to the below show as the Aussie gardening superstars talk about dealing with soursobs (and hopefully similar species in Oxalis genus). Listen at 22:30 and 32:23.

  - [Tallback Gardening 270811](http://mpegmedia.abc.net.au/local/adelaide/201108/r819626_7412696.mp3)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i can target it with the right treatment.

Comment: @Valamas No worries and good luck...

Comment: Where I come from (SA) it is called soursob and as far as I know its binomial name is Oxalis pes-caprae. It is an extremely well known weed throughout the agricultural regions of Australia and some studies identify it as a health risk for grazing livestock. You can use it as a herb apparently, though most people spend countless hours of their lives trying to kill it!

Comment: Also, there was recently advice on the local ABC891 gardening radio program about killing soursobs. If you like I'll try and find it (the podcast snippet) again. The main thrust though was that they have to be poisoned at a very specific time of year (late August if I recall) and by now it is too late for this year :| Good luck!

Comment: @Lisa: Thanks for the info. I had a look at the Abc website and could not find a history of podcasts. If you know where that list is, I would be fine to listen through them to find that information.

Comment: @Valamas I think this might be it: [891's Talkback Gardening with Jon Lamb and Ashley Walsh](http://www.abc.net.au/local/stories/2010/02/15/2819886.htm) -- Lisa can mock me if I'm wrong... Plus this: [Gardening Australia](http://www.abc.net.au/gardening/video/download.htm) -- looks interesting...

Comment: @MikePerry you're spot on. It's 891 talkback gardening with gardening superstar Jon Lamb, but that link doesn't take you to the podcasts. I'll get back with a link to the right one.

Comment: @Lisa this podcast link: http://www.abc.net.au/adelaide/features/garden.xml -- is on [that page](http://www.abc.net.au/local/stories/2010/02/15/2819886.htm), is it not correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1563/discussion-between-lisa-and-mike-perry)

Comment: @Valamas Dealing with soursobs (and hopefully similar species in Oxalis genus) at 22:30 mins in: http://mpegmedia.abc.net.au/local/adelaide/201108/r819626_7412696.mp3

Comment: LOL, thank you very much. I was listening while working and got to 12min. Skipped up to that time and can hear it. Thank you so much for taking the time.